# YII send array or array of array from view to controller action via form post

Tags: php, arrays, post, yii

I have one question with two different type of data.

I have a view in Yii, which has got a form control. I want to send an array, and an array of array to the controller, to my create action.

The array is : `$arraySons = ('albert','francis','rupert');`

The array of array is `$arrayFather = ('1'=>array(6,7,8));`

I must use some control, so the form will post it in `$_POST`?... or this can't be done and I must use JavaScript?

Comment: not sure if this will work, but worth a try, `<?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('name' , 'value', array('id' => 'hiddenInput')); ?>`

Comment: Oh no sorry, that is for html options

Comment: no. It doesnt send arrays to controller. Hiddenfield only accepts an string, like value in your example

Comment: I am starting to see your problem now. I guess you could use javascript to pass the array's as ajax to the controller, save the data as a session variable, and then when you move on to the next action you can access them from the controller again?

Comment: Or alternatively, if this is the same controller that you used to render this view, just save the data at this time as a session variable, then when you come back you can access again.

Comment: Thanks @Cookie_J5. Yes I know about session and javascript. I want to know if there is any posibility to do it through Yii controls.. or a Yii way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, in HTML forms you can create an array by having more than one field with the same name, and a array notation.

```
<input name="sons[]">
<input name="sons[]">
```

When you submit the form $_POST['sons'] will be an array, and can be handled as follows :

```
foreach ($_POST['sons'] as $son) {

    echo 'Son of the father is '.$son."\n";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your form as in the answer of @crafter. I just wirte more details:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sons[]" value="albert">
<input  type="hidden" name="sons[]" value="rupert">
```

and so on

and then for the fathers you would do something similar:

```
<input  type="hidden" name="father[1][]" value="6">
<input  type="hidden" name="father[1][]" value="7">
<input  type="hidden" name="father[1][]" value="8">
```

But if the user does not need to see the data, you could maybe prepare a JSON object with the data, and post it in 1 field, which seem much easier for me

```
<input  type="hidden" name="father" value="<?= json_encode($arrayFather); ?>">
<input  type="hidden" name="sons" value="<?= json_encode($arraySons); ?>">
```

and then in your action you can get the data from post and decode it with `json_decode`

```
$myArrayFather = json_decode($_POST['father']);
$myArraySons = json_decode($_POST['sons']);
```

Comment: thank you for the detail. When I use json_encode, like this        <?php $arrayFather = array('1'=>'6'); ?>

<input  type="hidden" name="father" value="<?php json_encode($arrayFather); ?>"> ... then i look in server, and father is a blank string. I missing something?

Comment: yes :) a little small thing - you do not `echo` the value - change it into:  `value="<?php echo json_encode($arrayFather); ?>">`

Comment: WONDERFULl this solution